# UML abstraction

Tags: oop, uml

I have one abstract `class1` which has abstract `method1()`.
`Class2` implements `class2` and overrides `method1()`.
`Class3` extends `class2` and overrides `method1()`.

Which of the two solutions in the image is the correct one according to UML?

[image: uml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is correct - although solution 1 is even less correct than solution 2.  First, there are some syntactic things you need to sort:

1. Your diagram shows the relations among classes as Binary Associations.  They're not - they're subtype relations.  Those have a different graphical syntax.
2. Abstract items (classes/methods) should be shown in italics.

There are also 2 semantic things you need to sort; some hints:

1. A class can't implement another class.  A class can implement an interface or extend (subtype) another class.
2. You need to draw the relationships between the classes correctly.  Big hint: this is where solution 2 is more correct than solution 1.  You need to figure out why.

hth.

Comment: yea class1 and class2 are abstract classes. so class2 is implements class1 and class3 extends class2 so class3 does not have a direct relation with class1 right ?. thats why the second solution is more correct

Comment: Correct. class3 doesn't have a direct relation with class1 and hence the reason solution 2 is more correct.  Careful with your first sentence though: class2 can't _implement_ class1 for the reasons I stated above.  Finally, assuming this is homework: please tag as such.  Honesty on that front will pay dividends.